# What is the difference in using a global variable with $ in a function and without $ in a function?

Tags: bash, shell

So I declare a global variable at the start then I go into a function and try to change it. However it works when I use the `$` key and does not when I do not use the key.

Location and the ball are both global variables

```
if [ theball -eq 1 ];then
       location=$(thefunction1)
fi
```

This does not work

However,this works

```
if [ $theball -eq 1 ];then
    location=$(function1)
fi
```

Also, what would be the difference if I had the code like this, with a $ on location as well.

```
if [ $theball -eq 1 ];then
    $location=$(function1)
fi
```

What is the difference between calling global variables with `$` and without. Is one only used for assigning values and the other to get the value stored within the variable.

Comment: Much will depend on `thefunction1` and `function1`. You are assigning the output produced by both functions within a *command substitution*. Without seeing both, there is no way to answer. (and always `"quote"` your variables inside `[...]`) Further `$location=$(function1)` is just *wrong*.

Comment: Use `$` to *get* the value of a variable, not to *set* the value. `[ theball -eq 1 ]` causes an error because it's trying to do an integer comparison involving the string "theball", which is not an integer. `[ $theball -eq 1 ]` works (if the variable `theball` is set to an integer), but `[ "$theball" -eq 1 ]` is a bit safer in case `theball` contains something weird. `$location=something` causes an error because it first gets the value of `location`, then tries to execute something like `5=something` (and it tries to execute it in a confused way).

Comment: Question IMHO should be updated, as the behaviour observed is not related to the scope of the variables (global or local) but it's more linked to a basic understanding of accessing the value of a variable vs her name with bash.